# what kind of electrical boxes and fashioning methods are best for metal framing?

Tags: wiring

What kind of electrical boxes and fastening methods are best for metal studs?  Are there special boxes that are best to use?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall, the main differences are using appropriate metal screws to attach (standard) boxes, and using bushings (should be either provided with framing or easily available from the framing supplier or an electrical supplier) to protect wires passing through the framing.

[This guide](http://www.steelframing.org/PDF/quicklinks/SFA_Trades_Guide_11-08.pdf) from "steelframing.org" might be a helpful read.